# jQuery.wrap where contents not a direct descendant

Tags: javascript, jquery, replacewith

I am trying to wrap selected nodes in a non-trivial structure, where the node will not (necessarily) be a direct descendant. It seems that `wrap()` is insufficient to use in a one-liner.

I got it to work using `replaceWith`, using placeholder syntax to `replace` the original HTML. The following works fine and could easily be wrapped in a jQuery plugin. But I am curious if there is a better solution.

```
var template = '<div>\
                  <div>...</div>\
                  <div>{{original}}</div>\
                  <div>...</div>\
                </div>';

$('p').each(function() {
  var o = $(this).html();
  $(this).replaceWith(template.replace('{{original}}', o));
});
```

Comment: Can I suggest you leave it alone???

Comment: @jondavidjohn, yeah, probably :-) I wrapped it up in a jQuery plugin and it works fine. I hadn't figured out how to do it (as shown above) until I was almost finished writing the question! Still, if there's some built-in functionality which already does this, I'd like to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more complex templates, you will want to look into the [jQuery Template Plugin](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/). It's still in beta, but it looks like it should provide a lot of flexibility. My original solution is still more compact, but using the [`jQuery.tmpl()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/) function is close to a workable solution.

For the simpler cases, as described above, you're probably better off wrapping it in a 2-line plugin, [like so](http://randomland.net/zourtney/2011/02/jquery-template-wrap):

```
$.fn.templateWrap = function(template) {
  return this.each(function() {
    var o = $(this).html();
    $(this).replaceWith(template.replace('{{original}}', o));
  });
}
```

Then call it using:

```
$('#target').templateWrap('<div>...{{original}}...</div>');
```

(Download [jquery.templatewrap.min.js](http://randomland.net/sites/default/files/zourtney/files/jquery.templatewrap.min_.js_.txt))